# Get file from FTP server to Tibco but Tibco access denied folder

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9VX5.png)

I want to get file from FTP server to folder DataSi but Tibco notification E:\DataSi access denied. Help Me

Console notification: 
15:31:49.681 ERROR [bwEngThread:In-Memory Process Worker-1] com.tibco.bw.core - 


    File [E:\DataSi] was not found due to fault [E:\DataSi (Access is denied)].-{ActivityName=WriteFile, ProcessName=parsemtmessage.SubProcessGetAllFileFTPServer, ModuleName=ParseMTMessage}
    TIBCO-BW-PALETTE-FILE-500020
    E:\DataSi


TIBCO-BW-CORE-500050: The BW process [parsemtmessage.SubProcessGetAllFileFTPServer] instance faulted, JobId [bw0a100], ProcessInstanceId [bw0a101], ParentProcessInstanceId [bw0a100], Module [ParseMTMessage:1.0.0.qualifier], Application [ParseMTMessage.application:1.0].
    TIBCO-BW-CORE-500051: Activity [WriteFile] fault.
    com.tibco.bw.palette.file.runtime.fault.FileNotFoundFault: File [E:\DataSi] was not found due to fault [E:\DataSi (Access is denied)].-{ActivityName=WriteFile, ProcessName=parsemtmessage.SubProcessGetAllFileFTPServer, ModuleName=ParseMTMessage}
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\DataSi (Access is denied)

15:31:49.697 ERROR [bwEngThread:In-Memory Process Worker-1] com.tibco.bw.core - 


    File [E:\DataSi] was not found due to fault [E:\DataSi (Access is denied)].-{ActivityName=WriteFile, ProcessName=parsemtmessage.SubProcessGetAllFileFTPServer, ModuleName=ParseMTMessage}
    TIBCO-BW-PALETTE-FILE-500020
    E:\DataSi


TIBCO-BW-CORE-500050: The BW process [parsemtmessage.Process] instance faulted, JobId [bw0a100], ProcessInstanceId [bw0a100], ParentProcessInstanceId [-], Module [ParseMTMessage:1.0.0.qualifier], Application [ParseMTMessage.application:1.0].
    TIBCO-BW-CORE-500051: Activity [WriteFile] fault.
    com.tibco.bw.palette.file.runtime.fault.FileNotFoundFault: File [E:\DataSi] was not found due to fault [E:\DataSi (Access is denied)].-{ActivityName=WriteFile, ProcessName=parsemtmessage.SubProcessGetAllFileFTPServer, ModuleName=ParseMTMessage}
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\DataSi (Access is denied)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with the ftp server administrator that the user account you are using to connect to the ftp server has read access for the mentioned folder (E:\DataSi (Access is denied)). If this is the case you need to check you are using the correct user account.

Answer (score 0):

"java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\DataSi (Access is denied)"

This clearly indicates that **proper permissions** aren't in place to access the folder. Please check if the user account has **read/write access** for that particular folder.